# Como ter mais de um requisição GET?

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-web-api

Eu quero poder buscar os meus items pelo nome e essa função também é uma requisição get só que já tem outras requisições Get queria entender como ter quantas eu quiser

Eu entendi que o programa não sabe para qual ir

da esse erro aqui:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>   AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints. Matches:

desafio.Controllers.ItemController.Get (desafio)
desafio.Controllers.ItemController.Buscar (desafio)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DefaultEndpointSelector.ReportAmbiguity(CandidateSet candidates)

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<List<Item>> Get()
    {
        return _itemService.Get();
    }

    [HttpGet("{id}", Name = "GetItem")]
    public ActionResult<Item> Get(string id)
    {
        var item = _itemService.Get(id);
        if (item == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return item;
    }

    [HttpGet("{name}")]
    public ActionResult<List<Item>> Buscar(string name)
    {
        var item = _itemService.Buscar(keyword);
        if(item == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return _itemService.Get();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

é só nomear o caminho diferente, ex:

```
[HttpGet("Buscar/{name}")]  // seu get vai controller/buscar/name
    public ActionResult<List<Item>> Buscar(string name)
    {
        var item = _itemService.Buscar(keyword);
        if(item == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return _itemService.Get();
    }
```

Comment: Muito obrigado Lucas, eu estava fazendo parecido mas não dava o resultado que eu esperava, você me ajudou muito, obrigado!!!!